# Management of scipy.spatial.distance.cdist output

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-spatial

Good morning everyone, if I am writing something in a wrong way please let me know. However I am using the afore mentioned method in python to get pairwise CA-CA distances of two sets of residues in a pdb file, sometimes there are two CA due to incertainties and this will change the output from:

`[[X]]`

to:

`[[X X]]`

where X are floats, sometimes the output is `[[]]` and some other times is `[]`, how can manage all these exceptions in a smart way? tried to convert those to string and .strip something here and there, didn't really work, at the moment the error I get is the following:

`if distmap[0][0]:`

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Which should be due to the `[]` case, I need to append these values to a list in a `str(round(float(X),2))` format. The blank cases I would prefer to not be reported as 0 but for istance an insanely huge number such as 100, or not reported at all.
Please let me know if you need more info and if I need to change the form of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
if distmap.size == 0:
    # Do something when distmap is empty
```

You can also use `distmap.shape` to identify its dimension.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it will work for every case, but for now it worked fine, but i changed it to :
`if distmap.size != 0:
    TDI.append([int(res[0]), int(res[1]), res[2], str(round(float(distmap[0][0]), 2))])`